# TFS 2010 : Use the label name in build number format

Tags: msbuild, build

I'm trying to setup a build with TFS 2010. I want the build number format to be something like **$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(version)** where **$(Version)** is the version (label or changeset) specified in the "Get Version" field in the "Queue Build" dialog. If there's no specific version, I would like the version to be **latest**.

I googled for that but I'm new to msbuild and TFS build so I'm not sure what I should look for to get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.UpdateBuildNumber activity in your build template (e.g. DefaultTemplate.xaml) is what does the work of transforming your build number format string.  It takes any of the parameters listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh190719), however, the version (your changeset or label) is not one of the supported tags.

One workaround I've found that does not require custom code is to edit the BuildNumberFormat argument immediately before the Update Build Number activity uses it.

1. Open up the xaml template using the GUI editor and find the Update Build Number activity at the top.
2. Find the Primitives -> Assign activity in the Toolbox.  Drag and drop that just above the Update Build Number.
3. Edit the Assign activity to assign the value `String.Format("$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_{0}$(Rev:.r)", BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion)` to `BuildNumberFormat`.  The SourceGetVersion will pull the changeset number or label used to trigger the build.  If nothing is specified in the Get Version dialog when you're queuing your build then the changeset number is used by default (e.g. C16044).

Comment: For anyone else using TFS2013 - This does not seem to work and fails with the following error: "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDetails is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'"

Comment: @andersr On the contrary - for me it works exactly as described (Tfs2013.Update2)

Comment: Works great on TFS 2010!

Answer (score 1):

this is a good start
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/06/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-10-Include-Version-Number-in-the-Build-Number.aspx

Comment: Looks good but not exactly what I'm looking for. But thanks anyway for your help.