# TFS Build 2010 - Set Initial Build Number

Tags: tfsbuild

Is there a way to set the initial build number in TFS 2010? I am using the TFS build number (BuildDetail.BuildNumber) in my File Versions. On my Main branch everything works nicely. However, when I create my release branches and create new CI build definitions for them, the build number restarts at 1. I want to tell TFS to start at a particular number. Or maybe just use the same pool of numbers for all branches. So a build on the main branch might be 100 then a build on a release branch will be 101. Anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BuildNumber property generates its value from provided format inside build definitions process settings "Build Number Format" - default value :
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
Where revision is the increment number your probably referring - the point of this number is to ensure build number is unique. This value is incremented only when there is already identical build number in system.

You can add any literal characters as well but will require you to update the number for each build..

If you want to implement something more sophisticated you will have to look at customizing the Team Build, this might help you excellent series of articles "Customize Team Build 2010", specifically this should set you on way:
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/06/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-10-Include-Version-Number-in-the-Build-Number.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you refering to the buildId? The build number in the process tab can surely be set to however you'd like. If you are refering to buildId, there might be a way through the database, but I would be really wary of doing it that way. I would have no idea what the implications would be. I would not try that.

Comment: I am using the BuildDetail.BuildNumber property.

Answer (score 1):

You could include the changeset number in your build numbers.  That's unique across branches so it might meet your needs.  I've got steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16321699/992425 for pulling the `BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion` into the `BuildNumberFormat`.

If you're trying to push the number back down to your File Versions then it might not be sufficient.